# Postgres uses usual array index instead of intarray index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have the column `agg_series_id` with the type `integer[]` with `intarray` index created on it. Query for creating index is:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_agg_series_id ON some_tbl USING gin (agg_series_id gin__int_ops);
```

It is about 500k rows it the table. I have such execution plan for the query `SELECT count(*) FROM some_tbl WHERE agg_series_id <@ ARRAY [1]`:

```
Aggregate  (cost=129835.91..129835.92 rows=1 width=8)
 ->  Seq Scan on some_tbl  (cost=0.00..129835.89 rows=11 width=0)
       Filter: (agg_series_id @> '{1}'::integer[])
```

As can be seen from the plan the intarray index is not used. Shutting down `seqscan` by setting `set enable_seqscan=off;` is not changed the plan. I tried to increase statistics for the column and tried to execute `VACUUM ANALYZE`.

But if I remove the intarray extension (`gin__int_ops`) from the index and then create a new index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_agg_series_id2 ON some_tbl USING gin (agg_series_id);
```

In this case the new index is used in the execution plan:

```
Aggregate  (cost=55.93..55.94 rows=1 width=8)
 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on some_tbl  (cost=12.08..55.91 rows=11 width=0)
       Recheck Cond: (agg_series_id @> '{1}'::integer[])
       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_agg_series_id2  (cost=0.00..12.08 rows=11 width=0)
             Index Cond: (agg_series_id @> '{1}'::integer[])
```

So the question is: why the intarray index is not used in execution plan for `integer[]` column and the usual array index is used instead? Or maybe I can adjust some settings or types so the intarray index can be used?

PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit

Comment: A regular GIN index [supports the `<@` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html#GIN-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If a regular GIN index supports the <@ operator, why do we need `gin__int_ops` option at all then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you specify the `gin__int_ops` option with some certain schema? Because it looks like you have the intarray extension installed into another schema. You see the `<@` operator (along with `&&`, `@>`) of the intarray extension is [equivalent to built-in operators of the same name](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) so if there isn't the intarray extension installed, the `<@` operator will be used as the operator of a regular array. In this turn the regular GIN index will be used.

You can check if there is the intarray extension installed in your scheme. Try to use the [`icount`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) function in the some query. If you get an error with a 'not found' message so you don't have the intarray extension in the current schema. If so you can change the current schema with the command `SET search_path TO some_another_schema`.

Maybe there would be less confusion if a differing operator would be used for the intarray operations instead of a built-in one.

Comment: Yes, I removed the schema name from the query to clarify the question. I didn't think that it is important. After using `SET search_path TO` everything works, thank you.